# how to get the count for the given Json response in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

In the api I am getting the following data and in this I need to get the total names count in all arrays

```
{
  "Flat": [
    {
      "price": "$5.00", 
      "id": 11, 
      "name": "Fixed"
    }
  ], 
  "United Parcel Service": [
    {
      "price": "$109.12", 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "worldwide Expedited"
    }, 
    {
      "price": "$120.18", 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "worldwide Express saver"
    }
  ]
}
```

i had tried the following code to get the names count in all arrays

```
    var arrayss =  [String:AnyObject]()
    var keys = [String]()
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVgbyVQGmq?indent=2"
    var totalCount = 0
func shippingmethodURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                self.arrayss = jsonObj as! [String : AnyObject]
                self.keys = jsonObj?.allKeys as! [String]
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
                    let sectionHeight = self.arrayss.count * 31
                    let cellHeight = self.keys.count * 44
                    self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(sectionHeight + cellHeight)
                    self.heightConstant = Int(self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant)
                    self.delegate?.heightConstant(int: self.heightConstant!)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `Foundation` data types when they have native Swift equivalents (such as `NSURL` and `NSDictionary`).

Other than that, your problem is that you are counting the keys of your dictionary. However, what you want to do is iterate through your dictionary, use conditional casting to check if the value associated with that key is an array and if it is an array, check if the dictionary elements of the array have a *"name"* key, if they do, increment the count, otherwise do nothing.

Also don't use force unwrapping and force casting when parsing a JSON data, since in a network response there is a real possibility that those can fail and your app would crash.

```
func shippingmethodURL() {
    guard let url = URL(string: self.urlString) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let data = data, let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:AnyObject] {
            self.arrayss = jsonObj
            self.keys = Array(jsonObj.keys)

            var totalCount = 0
            for value in jsonObj.values {
                if let array = value as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for element in array {
                        if let name = element["name"] as? String {
                            totalCount += 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //update UI and other variables here
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: what is dict.values there it is not declared so i am getting error ?

Comment: It was a typo, should have been `jsonObj.values`.

Comment: then where to reload table view data here

Comment: At the end of your completionHandler, after the outer loop. Check my updated answer.

Comment: self.keys = jsonObj?.allKeys as! [String] i need to get all keys how to get it

Comment: You mean the outer keys? Such as "Flat", "United Parcel Service", etc? Just use `jsonObj.keys`.

Comment: i declared keys as [String] in my code is this the problem for that ?

Comment: `self.keys = Array(jsonObj.allKeys)` gives you the keys as an array of Strings.

Comment: value of [string: anyObject] has no member 'allKeys' its showing the error now

Comment: My bad, that was a typo, use `self.keys = Array(jsonObj.keys)`.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: and one thing i was also a electrical & electronics engineer like u

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answer you should always consider native Swift types other than prefix with `NS` (i.e. `NSDictionary`, `NSURL`). So you should use native Swift types as `Dictionary` and `URL`. And another thing is ***it's better to use `Any` other than `AnyObject`***. You can have a look [here](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-any-in-swift/) why I'm saying this.

Saying enough, you should take a look at:

```
var arrayss = [String:Any]()
var keys = [String]()
let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVgbyVQGmq?indent=2"
var nameKeyCount = 0

func shippingmethodURL() {
    guard let url = URL(string: self.urlString) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let data = data, let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any] {
            self.arrayss = jsonObj
            self.keys = Array(jsonObj.keys)
            // Now you want to know the count for `name` key
            // Below is the standard way in swift.
            // Looping through each of the object is cumbersome
            self.nameKeyCount = jsonObj.flatMap { $0.value.flatMap { $0.filter { $0.key == "name" } } }.count

            // As URLSession's data task is an asynchronous task and done in a thread other than main thread, you should have your main thread to update any UI related thing
            Dispatch.main.async {
                // update UI here
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```